# java.lang.NullPointerException at com.activeandroid.Model.<init>(Model.java:53)

Tags: android, activeandroid

I'm trying to add a new table with `ActiveAndroid` and I'm getting:.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.activeandroid.Model.<init>(Model.java:53)
```

on:

```
public Model() {
        this.idName = this.mTableInfo.getIdName();
    }
```

As I understand from the [documentation](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Schema-migrations) that I don't need a migration for new table so I created only the class that extends `Model` class with all needed annotation.

**How do I add this new table right?**

Comment: Did you make sure to extend the Application class OR include the "com.activeandroid.app.Application" class as in Application in the Manifest?

Comment: I'm doing ActiveAndroid.initialize(this); This is a working project I'm just trying to add new table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have mentioned the models using like these

```
  <meta-data
        android:name="AA_MODELS"
        android:value="models.objectModel.UserModel,
        models.objectModel.TestsModel,models.objectModel.AllergyModel" />
```

then make sure that the new model is also specified here , i got the same problem and solved it by adding new model to this list ..